# Golang go test specific directory

Tags: go

I want to test files in all other paths except the `static` path.

I had checked the information,can pass `go test -run` ,but I have been try to fail

Below is my project path structure

```
api/...
common/...
static/...    //except this
...
```

Comment: Please add the command and the exact error message.

Comment: What's wrong with `./...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this command to exclude a specific folder:

```
 find ./ -type d  ! -path "./static*" ! -path "./.git*"  -exec go test -v "{}" \;
```

Comment: my solution `for filename in $(ls $pwd); do if [ -d "$filename" ] && [ "$filename" != "static" ];then go test ./$filename/...; fi; done`